# Formatting floppy disk for Apple llc

Tags: formatting, basic, floppy

I am trying to write a simple BASIC program on an old Apple llc computer, but I cannot figure out how to format this blank floppy disc so that I can use it to save a program onto it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Next time try *providing more details*. What exactly happens when you try formatting the floppy disk? What errors do you get?

Eitherway, after some research try checking out these links

[https://discussions.apple.com/thread/771709#:~:text=The%20FDHD%20(Floppy%20Disk%20High,800K%20(Mac%20format)%20diskettes.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/771709#:%7E:text=The%20FDHD%20(Floppy%20Disk%20High,800K%20(Mac%20format)%20diskettes.)

^^ An old apple thread talking about floppy disks,

Or if you have a windows computer you may try using that machine to format the flopy disk

https://howto.org/how-to-format-a-floppy-disk/

If **all** else fails, (and this is where more details would have been helpful) try buying USB floppy disk drive? Something like this?
[https://www.amazon.com/External-Floppy-Portable-Windows-Required/dp/B00RXEWOAA/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=usb+floppy+drive&qid=1645624124&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RXEWOAA)